# Debugging MongoDB in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I just started off with programming in C#. I'm using Visual Studio to make a Mongo database and followed a tutorial to get the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

namespace NetCoreWeb.Repositories
{
    public class BreakoutStrategyConfig
    {
        [BsonElement("id")]
        public ObjectId id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("stock")]
        public string stock { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("trade_limit")]
        public int trade_limit { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("interval")]
        public double interval { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("exit_pl")]
        public double exit_pl { get; set; }


    }

   }
```

This is the implementation:

```
using System;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace NetCoreWeb.Repositories
{
    public class BreakoutStrategyConfigImpl : IBreakoutStrategyConfig

    {

        private readonly IMongoDatabase _db;

        public BreakoutStrategyConfigImpl()
        {
            MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://mymongo:27017");
            _db = client.GetDatabase("BreakoutStrategyConfig");
        }

            public ICollection<BreakoutStrategyConfig> GetAllBreakoutStrategyConfigs()
            {
                List<BreakoutStrategyConfig> configs = new List<BreakoutStrategyConfig>();
                var cursor = _db.GetCollection<BreakoutStrategyConfig>("BreakoutStrategyConfigs").Find(new BsonDocument()).ToCursor();
                foreach (var document in cursor.ToEnumerable())
                {
                    configs.Add(document);
                }
                return configs;
            }

            public BreakoutStrategyConfig GetBreakoutStrategyConfigById(ObjectId id)
            {
                return _db.GetCollection<BreakoutStrategyConfig>("BreakoutStrategyConfigs").Find(config => config.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            }

            public void AddBreakoutStrategyConfig(BreakoutStrategyConfig config)
            {
                _db.GetCollection<BreakoutStrategyConfig>("BreakoutStrategyConfigs").InsertOne(config);
            }

            public void DeleteBreakoutStrategyConfig(ObjectId id)
            {
                _db.GetCollection<BreakoutStrategyConfig>("BreakoutStrategyConfigs").DeleteOne(config => config.id == id);
            }

            public void UpdateBreakoutStrategyConfig(BreakoutStrategyConfig config)
            {
                _db.GetCollection<BreakoutStrategyConfig>("BreakoutStrategyConfigs").ReplaceOneAsync(n => n.id.Equals(config.id)
                    , config
                    , new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
            }
     }
}
```

My problem is pretty simple: I made the classes and tables but I'm not sure how to test this.

How can I see a list of collections a documents in the database?

Do I write a script in Program.cs (automatically created)?

Essentially, I just need to see if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean that collection and database is created by your code or not? 
if yes, you don't need to manually run the script to create db and collection. 
If DB / collection is not exist then mongodb will automatically creates it.

Comment: I mean, how do I check the databases and see what is in it?

Comment: There tools for that. Robo3T / MongpDB compass etc. you are use it for look into the database.